# Archive unknown or damage error while compressed file in php

Tags: php, file, download, directory, zip

I'm trying to write code to zip a file and download it. My problem is when I download and open the file, I get the error

> The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Here's my code:

```
<?php
try{
$db_conn = new DBController();
$db_conn->prepare("SELECT filetypename FROM dirlistening WHERE dadroot = :BasName AND sonbas = :BasDirName");
$db_conn->bind(':BasName', $parentBasIndex);
$db_conn->bind(':BasDirName', $currentBas);
$db_conn->execute();
$dbzipoutput = $db_conn->getAll();
$db_conn->free();
$files = array();
    if(!is_null($dbzipoutput)){
        foreach($dbzipoutput as $azip){
            $files[] = $azip->filetypename;
        }
    }
//$file_names = array("'" . implode( $filess, "','" ) . "'");
$file_names = $files;
    function zipSourceFilesDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path){
          $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE){
            exit("cannot open ".$archive_file_name."\n");
        }else{
            foreach($file_names as $filelist){
                $zip->addFile($file_path.'/'.$filelist);
                $zip->addEmptyDir($file_path.'/'.$filelist);
                $zip->addFromString($file_path.'/'.$filelist, file_get_contents($file_path.'/'.$filelist));
                $zip->setArchiveComment("zipped on ".date('Y-M-d')."
                    \nDownloaded from: My website 
                    \nWebsite: http://www.example.com
                    \nProject Source: ".$file_path."
                    \nProject Url: http://example.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."
                    \nFILE COMMENT AND DESCRIPTION
                    \n none");  
            }
            $var = $zip->close();
            $download_file = true;
        }

        if($download_file){
            ob_get_clean();
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: private", false);
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$archive_file_name);
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
            print $zip_file;
            unlink($archive_name);
        }
        return $var;        
    }
    zipSourceFilesDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);  
}catch (PDOException $e){ echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: You `print $zip_file;` where is the `$zip_file` variable?

Comment: @developer i have tired to print `$archive_file_name` but still same please help me

Comment: Ok, as i see, you only print a variables names after zipping files, you need to read the `$archive_file_name` like `readfile($archive_file_name);`

Comment: @developer before when i read it echo some unknown characters and when i read again just now i get this window alert message `:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ns4ftZQy.zip.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Try again later, or contact the server administrator.`

Comment: I tried it and works well, try to replace  `print $zip_file; unlink($archive_name);` with `readfile($archive_file_name)` and remove `return $var;`